# "I've set different dimensions for the image size and the input shape in tf.keras.Input, but it still works during training."

Tags: tensorflow, keras, input, deep-learning, shapes

I have a question that has arisen during an experiment in model training, and I would like to ask it.
This is related to the difference between the Keras dataset image size and the model's input layer shape during training and evaluation.

When I load an image dataset using the Keras API, it looks something like the code below:

```
tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        train_root_path,
        'training',
        train_aug,    
        validation_fraction=0.2,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        image_size=(480, 365), #h_resize, w_resize
        # seed=seed,
        color_mode=color_mode
    )
```

"I've set the height to 480 and the width to 365, and I've configured the Keras Input layer shape as (365, 480, 3), like the example below:"

```
img_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (365, 480, 3)
#~~~
model = tf.keras.Model(img_input, x)
```

I expected this to result in an error during training, but it actually worked without any issues!
However, when I perform the evaluation, the error I expected actually occurs.

"ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 365, 480, 3), found shape=(None, 480, 365, 3)"

Is there something different about the Keras Input layer during training and evaluation?
I'm really curious. Thank you.

Comment: I tested a model that includes Global Average Pooling.

Comment: I could not replicate your problem. Please add a full minimum running example.